# Prolog- How to sum only part of list inside another list?

Tags: prolog

Define a recursive rule, in the form of 
`sum(Lst, Total)`, which can calculate the sum of a list of stated, where Lst is in the format of `[[s1, p1], [s2, p2], … [sn, pn]]`

so i only want sum p and s is not numbers. 
how can i done this?

```
sum([[az, ​7​], [ca, ​40​], [ne, ​3​], [ut, ​3​], [or, ​4​],Total).
```

it should return `Total = 60`. but my code is not returning anything

i have

```
sum([[_,X]|T],Total) :- 
    sum(T,Rest),
    Total is X + Rest.
```

Comment: You should try something first and post the code so that you can get a specific answer. Try reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only missing the base case where the list is empty!

```py
sum([],0).

sum([[_,X]|T],Total) :- 
    sum(T,Rest),
    Total is X + Rest.
```

Answer (score 1):

sum(L,Total):- total(L,0,Total).

sum([],Total,Total).

sum([[_|HT]T],Temp,Total) :- Temp1 is temp+HT,total(T,Temp1,Total).